# Problem with a circle in a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

$\textbf{Problem}$: The points $D$ and $E$ are marked on the sides $AB$ and $AC$ of the triangle $ABC$, respectively. Points $B$, $C$, $E$, and $D$ lie on the same circle. Find the radius of the circle described near the triangle $ADC$, if it is known that $\angle CDE =  \angle BAC$ and that the radius of the circle described near the triangle $ABC$ is $1$.

[image]

$\textbf{My solution attempts}$:  We can apply the sine theorem to a triangle $ABC$ and get $\frac{BC}{\sin \angle A} = 2 R$. Since the quadrilateral $DBCE$ is inscribed in a circle we get $\angle B + \angle E = 180, \angle D + \angle C = 180$. I don't know where to go next.

Comment: May be you mear the radius near triangle ADE is 1? am I right?

Comment: Of $ADC$, I corrected it

Comment: @Victor You mean in the last linegiven radius BDC=1?

Comment: Radius $ABC = 1$

Comment: What exactly does "circle described near a triangle" mean? Circumcircle? Incircle? Something else?

Comment: @Arthur, Incircle.

Answer (score 1):

It can be seen that triangles ADE and ABC are isosceles and $R_{ADC}= 1$ :

$\angle EDC+\angle EDA=\angle B+\angle BCD$

$\angle BDE+\angle BCE= \angle BDE + \angle ADE=180^o$

So: $ \widehat {BCE}=\widehat {EAD}$

So: $BC || DE$

$\widehat {EDC} = \widehat A=\widehat{DCB}$

Also : $\widehat{ADE}=\widehat{ABC}=\widehat B$

$(\widehat {ADE=B})+\widehat A+\widehat {BCD}=180^o$

That means $\widehat BDC=\widehat {BCD}$ and triangle $ABC$ is isosceles.

$\widehat{ADC}=\widehat A +\widehat B$

So:

$2R=\frac {AC}{Sin(A+B)}$

Due to statement we have:

$\frac {AC}{Sin B}=2\times 1=2$

also we have:

$\widehat {ADC}=\widehat A + \widehat B$

That means:

$2R=\frac{2 Sin (B)}{Sin (A+B)}$

$ \widehat A=180-2 \widehat B$

$Sin(A+B)=Sin(180-B)=Sin(B)$

$R=\frac {Sin B}{Sin B}=1$

Comment: According to your decision the triangle $ABC$ is rectangular and isosceles and the angle $\angle C = 90$. This can't be, you have a mistake.

Comment: Viktor, you are right .I am trying to correct it.